# Error: Can't set headers after they are sent after res.render() call

Tags: node.js, express

I'm getting the following error:

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at validateHeader (_http_outgoing.js:491:11)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:498:3)
    at Array.write (D:\UberGo\node_modules\finalhandler\index.js:285:9)
    at listener (D:\UberGo\node_modules\on-finished\index.js:169:15)
    at onFinish (D:\UberGo\node_modules\on-finished\index.js:100:5)
    at callback (D:\UberGo\node_modules\ee-first\index.js:55:10)
    at IncomingMessage.onevent (D:\UberGo\node_modules\ee-first\index.js:93:5)
    at emitNone (events.js:106:13)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:139:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:181:9)
```

My controller:

```
app.get('/rider/history', function(request, response,next) {
  rideHistory=[];
  rhController.getAllRides(request.session.riderId, function (err, result) {
    if (err) return handleError(err);
    if (result.length > 0) {                
      response.render('rider_history.html',{
        rideHistory: JSON.stringify(result),
        Title: config.title.history,
        moment: moment
      }); 
      response.end();
    }
  });

var Projection = {
    __v         : false,
    _id         : false, 
};
exports.getAllRides = function(riderId, callback){
    rideHistory.find({RiderId: riderId},Projection, callback);
};
```

When I am rendering my page so it's working fine but after calling of `JSON.stringify()` I am getting the above error. I don't know how to fix it or what am I doing wrong?

I want to show rider data into Google Maps and the returned data is not formatted.- that's the reason I have to use JSON.stringify(stringify).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DO NOT use both render and end method. If you use response method twice or more, **Error: Can't set headers after they are sent** happens

You do not need response.end method in express. Remove it and then your code will work.

render method already includes end feature.

Answer (score 1):

As per express's render method implementation

```
res.render = function render(view, options, callback) {
    var app = this.req.app;
    var done = callback;
    var opts = options || {};
    var req = this.req;
    var self = this;

    // support callback function as second arg
    if (typeof options === 'function') {
        done = options;
        opts = {};
    }

    // merge res.locals
    opts._locals = self.locals;

    // default callback to respond
    done = done || function (err, str) {
        if (err) return req.next(err);
        self.send(str);  // < - THIS LINE IS SENDING RESPONSE
    };

    // render
    app.render(view, opts, done);
};
```

It's sending response by default so you can send only one response to one HTTP request so in express you can use only one method from following only once per request.

- end()
- json()
- jsonp()
- render()
- send()
- sendFile()
- sendStatus()

You can not combine any of this method in one function so removing `response.end()` in you code will solve you problem.